# Importing plain JS code inside angular - 7

Tags: javascript, angular

I trying to import for the first time [this](https://github.com/not-implemented/hocr-proofreader) plain JS code inside my angular app.
I created a js file inside the App folder and I passed there all the code that located [here](https://github.com/not-implemented/hocr-proofreader/blob/master/hocr-proofreader.js) . 
I added the script inside my `scripts` Array in the angular.json file and set `allowJs` to `true`.
Inside my component JS file I importing the methods like that:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Util, HocrProofreader} from '../hocr';

const Utils = Util;
const Hocr = HocrProofreader;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ocr-compiler',
  templateUrl: './ocr-compiler.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ocr-compiler.component.css']
})
export class OcrCompilerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
      Utils.onReady(() => {
        var hocrProofreader = new HocrProofreader({
            layoutContainer: 'layout-container',
            editorContainer: 'editor-container'
        });
      })

      const hocr = '../../assets/1.jpg';
      Hocr.prototype.setHocr(hocr)
  }
}
```

And the HTML file looks like that

```
<div class="viewport">
  <div class="toolbar">
      <div class="logo">hOCR-Proofreader</div>

      <button id="toggle-layout-image">Image/Text</button>
      <div class="separator"></div>

      <span>Zoom:</span>
      <button id="zoom-page-full">Full Page</button>
      <button id="zoom-page-width">Page Width</button>
      <button id="zoom-original">Original</button>
      <div class="separator"></div>

      <button id="button-save">Save</button>
  </div>

  <div id="layout-container" class="container"></div>
  <div id="editor-container" class="container"></div>
</div>
```

The import work fine but I facing with an error:

```
AppComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentDocument' of undefined
    at Object.push../src/app/hocr.js.HocrProofreader.setHocr (hocr.js:106)
```

That refers to this code:

```
HocrProofreader.prototype.setHocr = function (hocr, baseUrl) {
    this.hocrBaseUrl = baseUrl;
    var hocrDoc = this.editorIframe.contentDocument; <===== Here

    // TODO: use baseUrl for images/components in hOCR - use <base>?

    hocrDoc.open();
    hocrDoc.write(hocr);
    hocrDoc.close();

    var self = this;
    var hocrRoot = hocrDoc.documentElement;
    hocrRoot.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
        self.mousePosition = {container: 'editor', x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY};
        self.onHover(event.target, true);
    });
    hocrRoot.addEventListener('mouseleave', function (event) {
        self.mousePosition = null;
        self.onHover(null, true);
    });
    hocrDoc.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
        if (!self.mousePosition || self.mousePosition.container !== 'editor') return;
        self.onHover(hocrDoc.elementFromPoint(self.mousePosition.x, self.mousePosition.y), true);
    });

    this.editorStylesheet = Util.createElem('link', {'type': 'text/css', 'rel': 'stylesheet', 'href': 'editor.css'});
    hocrDoc.head.appendChild(this.editorStylesheet);

    hocrDoc.body.contentEditable = true;

    this.setPage('first');
};
```

Comment: Typescript is a superset of Javascript anyway so pretty much all valid JS is also valid TS. Typing etc is optional. As for your issue, it looks like this.editorIframe is not defined, hence the error

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use JS inside Angular component. But there is a special place to include your script.

You can include script in angular.json file. Look for scripts array and include the path of your script.

```
"scripts": [
   "path of your script goes here"
]
```

After this in you component you can say at the very top before import (though it's not necessary):

```
declare var Utils;
```

and use Utils function.

Comment: As i mention inside my question. I already added it to the script array

Comment: Then you don't need to import it. Just use the declare statement and you can use your script.

Comment: Remove Hocr.prototype.setHocr(hocr) and try hocrProofreader .setHocr(hocr); in your compoent

Comment: No.`Property 'setHocr' does not exist on type 'typeof HocrProofreader'.ts(2339)`

Comment: The code you have posted, setHocr exist on the prototype of HocrProofreader. HocrProofreader.prototype.setHocr this line.

Answer (score 0):

The only missing here is to instantiate your object.
You can do it inside a service if you want.

HocrProofreader-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare const Util: any;
declare const HocrProofreader: any;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PRService{
  private util;
  private hpf;

  constructor() {
    this.util = new Util();
    this.hpf = new HocrProofreader({
      layoutContainer: 'layout-container',
      editorContainer: 'editor-container'
    });
  }

  setHocr(hocr) {
    this.hpf.setHocr(hocr);
  }
}
```

let me know if this works for you.